# Is it possible to block up-casting of references?

Tags: c++, oop

Consider a use case:

- you've got a copyable class `Base`, for which you don't really care what happens to it.
- inheriting publicly from it is a `Derived` class, which should not be convertible to `Base`. Not at all. Not even a reference to it, to a reference to `Base`, in other words it should be illegal to implicitly bind: `Derived& -> Base&`.

Note: `Derived` class can be copyable, just its internals should never ever be put into a regular `Base` object. Since banning initialization of `Base` from `Derived` directly can be done, the question remains if compilation can be prohibited from going around it: `Derived& -> Base& -> Base`.

Assume `static_cast`, pointers are not a problem - only automatic binding in functions calls.

Here is a basic example showing the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Derived;

class Base
{
public:
    Base(int var)
        : m_var(var)
    {
        std::cout << "Base default ctor with value: " << m_var << std::endl;
    }

    Base& operator=(const Derived&) = delete;
    Base& operator=(Derived&&) = delete;
    Base(const Derived&) = delete;
    Base(Derived&&) = delete;

    int m_var;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int var)
        : Base(var)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived default ctor with value: " << m_var << std::endl;
    }

    Base unprotect() const
    {
        std::cout << "Derived unprotected with value: " << m_var << std::endl;
        return Base(m_var);
    }
};

void foo(Base& base)
{
    std::cout << "foo with value: " << base.m_var << std::endl;
    // Base b2 = base; // just copied Derived, goal is to prohibit it!
}

int main()
{
    Base b1(1);
    foo(b1);

    Derived d1(2);
    foo(d1);            // is it at all possible to disallow implicit Derived& -> Base&?
    // rationale is to require explicit: Base& Dervied::getBaseRef()    

    // Base b2 = d1; // illegal: error: use of deleted function 'Base::Base(const Derived&)'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"inheriting publicly from it is a Derived class, which should not be convertible to Base."_ Why does it inherit `Base` then? That sounds pretty strange.

Comment: It seems more like a design problem than a code problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ due to an unfortunately large code *base based on `Base`*, where explicit casts would still be used, but you could keep a track of them *much easier*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree, however - can it be done?

Comment: @hauron: inherit privately. You can always re-scope the member functions you wish to `protected` or `public`. Another - much better - approach is to encapsulate, i.e., have a private member `Base` and delegate as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> inheriting publicly from it is a Derived class, which should not be convertible to Base. Not at all.

These two things are pretty much contradictory from OOP design point of view. I don't think there is a way in the language to prevent treating the derived object as a public base (by the way of implicit conversion of reference).

You could inherit `Base` non-publicly instead.

That would also prevent explicit casting - which you still want to be able to do - as well. But only outside the scope of the class. You could instead provide a member to get access to the base instance:

```
class Derived : Base
{
public:
    // ...
    Base& base() {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now, you can replace those explicit casts with call to `Derived::base`, which remains allowed while the implicit conversion does not.

```
Derived d;
Base& b = d;        // (implicit) conversion fails
Base& b = d.base(); // this works
```

You will probably also want to implement a `const` version of the function. I shall leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 3):

My standard way to do this is to use private inheritance and then lift all wanted methods, constructors and operators with `using`.

```
class Derived : private Base {
  public :
  using Base::Base;
  using Base::some_base_method;
}

int main(){
  Derived d1(2);
  d1.some_base_method();
}
```

For bad and worse this also make many future additions to Base innacessible via the public interface of Derived.
It also works well with templates including CRTP.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't inheriting to substitute (you explicitly say you don't want a derived to ever look be used as a base), I'll assume you're inheriting an implementation. In that case the answer is clear: Inherit `private`ly or possibly `protected` depending on your precise needs. This exactly prohibits all such conversions to the base class while still giving your child access to the implementation of the base.

If there are one or two base members you need to expose publicly you can always `using` them into the derived class.